# Google Maps Javascript API 204 errors

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, laravel

I'm using [gmaps](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) library in Laravel. I've created an API key on [google console](https://console.developers.google.com) and am passing my API key like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>` (I know this isn't good practice, but for now I'm just testing it.)

I am initializing the map using [gmaps basic](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/basic.html):

```
<html>
    <div id='map'></div>
</html>
...

<script>
    new GMaps({
      div: '#map',
      lat: -12.043333,
      lng: -77.028333
    });
</script>
```

Even though the map is loading, I keep getting these errors in the console:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?target=api&ev=api_viewport&cad=host:localhost%3A8000,v:25,r:1,mt:m,c:-12.043333%2C-77.028333,sp:0.01889x0.04892,size:1140x450,relsize:0.96,token:5qcrlsvho,src:apiv3,ts:9zqxca
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?target=api&ev=api_viewport&cad=host:localhost%3A8000,v:25,r:1,mt:m,c:34.149737%2C-118.135962,sp:0.01598x0.04892,size:1140x450,relsize:0.96,token:5qcrlsvho,src:apiv3,ts:9zqxmi
```

Can somebody explain to me what the errors are, or what causes them, or how I can fix them.

---

EDIT:

I've noticed that as I zoom-in/zoom-out more errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your body you need something like this:

```
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -12.043333, lng: -77.028333},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```